# Can I safely assume this INSERT succeeded?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I'm using MySQL with strict mode turned on. I am inserting data supplied by user through an HTML form. I've already done all my validation and this is the final step.

**Here is an excerpt from my PHP code:**

```
$sql = 'SET sql_mode = TRADITIONAL'; //last chance data validation
$mysqli->query($sql) or output_error('Database Error: Failed to set SQL mode');

$db_err_msg = 'Database Error: Failed to update profile summary';
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$tables['text']} (lngProfileId, memProfileText) VALUES(?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE memProfileText = VALUES(memProfileText)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or output_error($db_err_msg);
$stmt->bind_param('is', $profile_id, $_POST['memProfileText'])
    or output_error($db_err_msg);
$stmt->execute() or output_error($db_err_msg);
$stmt->close();

//if code reaches this point, can it assume insert/update succeeded?
```

**Note:** `output_error` is my error handler for fatal errors. It doesn't return; it exits.

Do I need to check for warnings? Or can I safely assume the insert/update succeeded? Is there some scenario that could cause a warning instead of an error even with strict mode turned on?

**EDIT:** I'm only concerned about things that should be considered *fatal* errors. If it was updated rather than inserted, that is of no concern to me. That's not an error.

Also, `last_insert_id` and `affected_rows` are meaningless in this case. If the user didn't make any changes, affected_rows will be 0 and the value of last_insert_id will not be updated.

My definition of *succeeded* in this case:

- it inserted the record or updated the record or did nothing if no changes were made
- it did not 'silently mangle my data'

Many newbie programmers make the mistake of *assuming* that a query succeeded without ever checking the return value or warnings. Their code *works*... under normal conditions.

*My question is:* **"Considering my code, with strict mode turned on, and the error checking I've done, is it safe to assume the query succeeded? Is that a correct or incorrect assumption? Should I also check for warnings or would that be redundant?"**

Comment: Did you test it? If it works, it works.

Comment: Yes, I tested it. It works with everything I threw at it. But I want to make sure there isn't some scenario that I'm not considering. I'm trying to ensure that I write robust code.

Comment: Do not solve problem that does not exist. You do not want to retest mysql, php driver functionality. Or you might as well write your own driver, DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think that it's probably a safe assumption, I figured *better safe than sorry*. I've added the following code directly after the execute statement before the close statement.

```
//I think this is probably redundant, but just in case
if ($mysqli->warning_count) {
    $warnings = $stmt->get_warnings();
    do {
        trigger_error('Database Warning (' . $warnings->errno . '): '
            . $warnings->message, E_USER_WARNING);
    } while ( $warnings->next() );
}
```

I've added the comment so that I remember why I did that.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the value of [`mysqli::info()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php) function.

If it inserts data the string will look something like this,

```
Records: 1 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0
```

Another function is [`mysqli::affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php). it returns the number of rows affected for last insert/update/delete query.

Comment: `mysqli::$info()` only works with certain statements. For a single insert, it returns an empty string. `mysqli::$affected_rows` will return 0 if the row already existed and wasn't changed. My question is asking *whether or not* I need to check for warnings *not how* to get that information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can safely assume that, but just for a double check Fetch the ID of the latest record that is inserted. If there is an id, it was inserted then

Comment: The id of the last insert won't tell me much in this case. See the edit to my question.